# Double cover of $\mathbb{P}^n$ branched along a hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

Also I wonder why the $\cup R_i/\sim$ is a cover of $\mathbb{P}^n$? How to see the  glued quotient rings as a cover? And what's the covering map?

Comment: Do you see $y_j=(x_i/x_j)^dy_i$ appearing in the gluing? $d$ is half of the degree of $f$, which will not make sense if the degree is not even.

Comment: @Mohan In general, do we require the degree to be even so have a double cover? And why do the $R_i$ form a cover?

Comment: If $F(Z) \in k[Z_1,\ldots,Z_n]$ is non-constant and not a square then $g(Z,w) = Z$ is a double cover $V( w^2-F(Z)) \to \Bbb{A}^n$ branched at the zeros of $F$. The question is when this map extends to a morphism to $\Bbb{P}^n$ and where is the branching on the remaining part $\Bbb{P}^n-\Bbb{A}^n$.

Comment: Yes, the only exception is taking two disjoint copies of projective space, then you get an unramified cover (rather uninteresting).